# How can i make so that for each item in a python list, a group of cells is copied in google sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, automation

In Google Sheets i have some rows with info a i need to fill in for each item in a list. 
I want to make it so that when i open the sheets document i already have the boxes to input the info depending on how many items there are in a python list.

Here is a visual example:
Visual example of what im trying to achieve[image]
In red would be text that doesnt change. The green cells are the forms i have to place info into.
To the left you see the default document (where we only have one item). To the right you see the document when the list has 3 items.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you to use for this [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) instead of python: The `SpreadsheetApp` is useful for easy copy-pasting of ranges and even more useful: you can use the `onOpen` trigger.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please _do not_ add a comment on your question to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for __requesting clarification__, leaving __constructive criticism__, or __adding relevant__ but minor __additional information__, __not__ for socializing.